# Routing URLs with language in Laravel

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, laravel

I want to add a localization information to my routes.

Currently my route definitions are:

```php
    Route::controller('browse');
    Route::controller('search');
    Route::controller('support');
    Route::controller('filter');
```

I want to change URLs from `/url/browse` to `/url/en/browse` etc.

If language is missing from the URL then the application should redirect to the same route with default language. This means accessing the old `/url/browse` would redirect to `/url/default/browse`.

I tried to make or find some simple solution with filters, unsuccessfully. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the Default Application Language and Supported Languages array in config.

If you put a language in the supported languages any route starting with that segment will set the current language and that will be considered the root url.

One difference from your requirements is instead of a redirection the default language will be accepted without the language in the url.

**Edit:** A filter which may help you with the redirect.

```php
Route::filter('pattern: *', array('name' => 'langredirect', function()
{
    $uri = Request::server('request_uri');
    $segments = explode('/', $uri);
    if ( ! array_get(Config::get('application.languages'), $segments[1]) )
    {
        return Redirect::to(URL::base() . '/' . Config::get('application.language') . $uri);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't find anything like this in my sources or even in docs. But on github in newest version i found it. Thanks! btw: any easy posiblility to make it redirect? (without editing laravel itself)

Comment: Reason is when en is default then: url/en and url leads to the same content and i want to have urls unique for search engines etc.

Comment: Solution with filter also crossed my mind, problem is. URL::to() and others does not add default language prefix. So, every page loaded to default will be redirected.

Comment: If you're already on a route which has the "prefix" whey will add it.

Comment: I've got default en and even when i go to adress url/en/whatever than URL::to('/whatever'); does not include en. I just tested it.

Comment: It works here. If it's only not working for the default language, then maybe the default is not added to the languages array.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. From if condition in your code i assumed that default language should not be in that array. Thanks. All works fine now.

Comment: Altough you may run into other problems, for example with forms. Form actions are not yet using language uris, so post/put/delete methods will run into the redirect and never actually run. You'll have to manually tell the form to include the language in the uri.